# Access Related Models

Tags: django, django-models

I have this 4 models.

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100, unique=True)


class PhoneUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, blank=True, null=True, 
                                   related_name='users', related_query_name='user',
                                   verbose_name=_('Department'))


class Extension(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(_('Extension'), max_length=settings.EXTENSION_MAX_LENGTH, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(PhoneUser, null=True, blank=True, related_name='extensions',
                         related_query_name='extension', verbose_name=_('Phone User'))


class PhonePIN(models.Model):
    pin = models.CharField(_('PIN'), max_length=settings.PIN_MAX_LENGTH)
    user = models.ForeignKey(PhoneUser, null=True, 
                             blank=True, related_name='pins', related_query_name='pin',
                             verbose_name=_('Phone User'))
```

I would like to get list of the Extension and PhonePIN objects from the Department object though their relationship with the PhoneUser object.

Is it possible to do that in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in full in the [documentation on making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
Extension.objects.filter(user__department__name='my department')
PhonePIN.objects.filter(user__department__name='my department')
```

or, if you already have a Department object:

```
Extension.objects.filter(user__department=my_department)
PhonePIN.objects.filter(user__department=my_department)
```

which will save you a JOIN.